# Is it possible to create a multi-class Text Classifier Tensorflow Lite model by TFLite Model Maker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec, text-classification, tensorflow-lite

I try to build an android apps to predict text classification using `AverageWordVecModelSpec` that have been provided by Tensorflow Lite Model Maker.

I'm using books content to test if my apps works. There are 3 books I've provided for this experiment. Here's the code:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git#egg=tensorflow-examples[model_maker]

import numpy as np
import os

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.data_util.text_dataloader import TextClassifierDataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task.model_spec import AverageWordVecModelSpec
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task import text_classifier

data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/datasetps'

model_spec = AverageWordVecModelSpec()

train_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'train'), model_spec=model_spec, class_labels=['categorya', 'categoryb'])
test_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'test'), model_spec=model_spec, is_training=False, shuffle=False)

model = text_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=model_spec)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_data)

model.export(export_dir='.')
```

It works when i only use 2 classes/books (same as examples provided by tensorflow team):
[it works normal even though it has small acurracy-- because i only takes 20 sample page per book as dataset actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhulI.png)

You can see that i have rational loss value here,
But i have a problem when i've try to add the 3rd class:

```
train_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'train'), model_spec=model_spec, class_labels=['categorya', 'categoryb', 'categoryc'])
test_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'test'), model_spec=model_spec, is_training=False, shuffle=False)
```

Here's the training result involving 3rd class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUPAV.png)

You can see that it's not rational for having loss value more than 1. 
I've tried to find which line of code (from Tensorflow Model Maker) that i should change to solve it and ended up to this question in this forum.

> So is it possible to have multiclass model for textclassifier using
>   AverageWordVecModelSpec TFlite model maker?

Comment: did you get the solution for the above thread ? for multi-level text classification

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I would suggest to encode your labels first and then follow the workflow:

```
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import text_classifier
from tflite_model_maker import TextClassifierDataLoader
from tflite_model_maker import ExportFormat

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('data_set.xls')
col = ['sentence', 'your_label']
df = df[col]

# Encoding happens here
df.your_label = pd.Categorical(df.your_label)
df['label'] = df.book_label.cat.codes


train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
train.to_csv('train.csv', index=False)
test.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)


spec = model_spec.get('average_word_vec')

train_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_csv(
   filename='train.csv',
   text_column='sentence',
   label_column='label',
   model_spec=spec,
   delimiter=',',
   is_training=True)
test_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_csv(
  filename='test.csv',
  text_column='sentence',
  label_column='label',
  model_spec=spec,
  delimiter=',',
  is_training=False)

model = text_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=5, epochs=4)

config = configs.QuantizationConfig.create_dynamic_range_quantization(optimizations=[tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_LATENCY])
model.export(export_dir='average_word_vec/', export_format=[ExportFormat.LABEL, ExportFormat.VOCAB])
```